# Is the unchecked keyword necessary in the VB.NET version of this C# statement?

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

I'm converting to VB.NET, which doesn't provide the `unchecked` keyword. But it appears to be unnecessary in this statement:

```
const int dwAccess = unchecked((int)0xC0000000);
```

I have two observations here:

1. `dwAccess` is declared as a constant
2. The value assigned falls well within the range of `System.Int32`

Given these, will it be safe to just go with this:

```vb
Const dwAccess As Integer = &HC0000000
```

It's being used in this context:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwAccess, int dwShareMode,
                                                IntPtr securityAttrs, int dwCreationDisposition,
                                                int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

**Clarification:** This question is not about whether the `unchecked` keyword is necessary in C#. *Clearly it is.* It's about whether the absence of the keyword in VB.NET precludes successful conversion of the statement.

Comment: isn't 0xC0000000 **out of the range** for a System.Int32? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ulwdVX

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, but Int32.MaxValue is =0x7FFFFFFF; for higher  numbers, you have to use UInt32, ain't it?

Comment: @GianPaolo: I've found that the value is the same in both VB [(link)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HwIa79) and C# [(link)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tNfQv8).

Comment: I think I understand. It seems VB is `unchecked` by default, while c# require specifying it if you want to assign 0xC0000000 to a System.Int32 variable

Comment: @GianPaolo — Yes, it seems that way.

Comment: No, other way around.  VB.NET is always checked with default project settings.  And C# is not.  That made life difficult for the C# team, they had to make an effort to do the checking at compile-time.  Not done so well, hard to do.  The VB.NET compiler is quite happy with overflow at compile-time, like it always was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a yes. It's redundant and can be removed.

[unchecked (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked)

> The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

---

Update, this answer should have been qualified.

If the original VB.NET code was unchecked then the equivalent C# code would function as is unchecked as well in the same way. Both will overflow and both will give the same results.

Comment: That's what I thought; thank you very much. (p.s. I can accept your answer in 11 minutes.)

Comment: @SeanVikoren: The keyword is required in C#, and VB.NET would reject an attempt to assign 3221225472 to an `Int32` or `Integer`.  In vb.net, however, unsuffixed hex constants in the range &h80000000 to &hFFFFFFFF are interpreted as negative values of type Int32.

Comment: @supercat The question needs editing.  I will undo the down-vote as soon as I can.

Comment: Of course, you could use a uint and avoid the negative

Comment: @Basic ~ Actually, that's a very good point. According to [this](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateFile), `uint` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The following is fine:

```
Const dwAccess As Integer = &HC0000000
```

There is no `unchecked` keyword in VB.Net, but there is a compile flag `-removeintchecks` [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/removeintchecks) that will cause integer overflow to not be checked for the entire program.

If the C# line is:

```
const int dwAccess = unchecked((int)0xC0000000);
```

then the VB.Net translation will look like this:

```
Const dwAccess As Integer = &HC0000000
```

Since `0xC0000000` is within the range of `uint`, but not `int`, the `unchecked` keyword in C# is used to convert the value to the `int` format.  In VB.Net, the conversion from a hex constant is automatic.

Comment: question is about c# ---> vb.net and was correctly answered a few months ago

Comment: The question is confusing. The question is not whether the `unchecked` is necessary in C#. It is necessary, as you note. The question is whether some equivalent is necessary when porting the code to VB.  It is not; VB allows unchecked arithmetic on integer constants by default.

Comment: @EricLippert: VB.NET does not allow unchecked arithmetic on integer constants, but regards an unsuffixed &C0000000 as a negative integer constant.  This behavior is analogous to how VB6 handled 16-bit hex constants, but I don't think it should have carried through to VB.NET, though there should have been an easy function to convert unsigned->signed quantities with wrapping.

Comment: I think you might want to uncheck my answer as correct

Comment: @Saruman ~ Thank you for your refreshing candor. Yes, with your consent here I'll ask Eric to post his clarification as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @EricLippert ~ Yes, you are correct. Thank you. Would you consider posting your clarification as an answer so I switch to yours. Also: I've edited my question, both title and body.

Comment: @TheGeneral ~ I just happened to see your comment just now (it wasn't addressed directly to me, so I wasn't notified at the time). Are you still of the same mind, that I might accept a different answer?